# How do I include variable name within a string of arguments such as: execlp("ls","ls"," /VARIABLE_NAME",Null);?

Tags: c, exec, execv

Basically this, I'd like to include variable within string of exec-related arguments, so if we have:

```
char myname[1024];
myname[1024] = "Michael";
```

And then when I call execlp I want myname to be injected inside so that "/home/variable" is seen by the program as "/home/Michael":

```
execlp("ls","ls","/home/'VARIABLE'",Null);
```

In c# we can use just "' + variable_name + '" but here pluses are seen as binary operator and escaping quotation marks doesn't for me...

Comment: Declare a `char` array, use `sprintf` to construct the desired string in that array, then use the array  for the call to `execlp`.

Comment: @TomKarzes: ok but can I input the name of this char array directly in execlp, as say: execlp("arrayname" .... and by the way: if execlp isn't the best function then I'd be fine to use execve or others if it's simpler to do system level of things such as cat, ls and others.

Comment: @TomKarzes sorry nevermind i got it now, you mean to simply "concatane" everything before hand and still use execlp as intended exept for the srguments part. Yes I know C doesn't use "strings" but i am using the word for simplicity...let's see.

Comment: You can do something like `char a[2000]; sprintf(a, "/home/%s", myname);` then you can use `a` as an argument to `execlp`.  That should be enough to give you the idea.  That's exactly what higher-level languages that support `+` for string concatenation are doing internally.  C is lower-level and you have to do it yourself.

Comment: Yes, I got it now thanks, appearantly I've declared "Michael" erronously too since I am getting now from gcc that this is "assignment from expression with array type" but anyhow I got it, I will point "myname" to "a" as in your example and overall got everything.

Answer (score 1):

As @TomKarzes mentioned in the comments, you can use

```
char a[2000]; sprintf(a, "/home/%s", myname);
```

and then have `a` as an argument to `execlp`.

Another issue is that you're assigning to `myname` incorrectly. Use this to get rid of that error:

```
char myname[1024] = "Michael";
```

---

However, another (potentially better) way of viewing the user's home directory would be (assuming that you're not hardcoding this to a user named `Michael`):

```
execlp("ls","ls",getenv("HOME"),(char *)NULL);
```

This uses the `getenv` function to get the user's home directory, and changes `Null` to `(char *)NULL`, to be clearer.